# How to capture output of a command window that is started by another application?

Tags: windows, command-line

## Problem

I use a GUI application that writes debug output to a command window (only there, no other log). When the application crashes, the command window disappears together with all the output.

## Question

How can I capture the output of the command window in a text file?

## What I've tried

As I found no way of interacting with the command window, I resorted to screen recording. This is far from ideal as I cannot select or copy the text easily.

Comment: What happens if you start the GUI program as `prog.exe > file.txt`?

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the suggestions. It writes some output, but definitely not all that is written to the debug window.

Comment: The command harrymc provided will only redirect the "Standard Output". The program may write additional information on the "Standard Error" output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `prog.exe > file.txt` works for all but the last output, we now know that
the GUI program uses standard output that can be captured under the right conditions.

You will need to use PowerShell with the cmdlet is called
[Tee-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7)
whose alias is `tee` (in the spirit of Linux).
This command outputs both to a file and also passes it to the standard output.

The PowerShell command to use may look like:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "\path\prog.exe" | tee -filepath \path\file.txt
```

This will send the output to `\path\file.txt` as well as to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a way to just "get" the data from the cmd window somehow. Like read it out from the memory or something. But I never seen such methods. **I would simply use AutoHotkey.**

Example: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/9953-how-to-capture-intire-cmdexe-text/

1) Find cmd window by Title. AutoHotkey has a tool called "Window Spy". https://amourspirit.github.io/AutoHotkey-Snippit/WindowSpy.html Use this tool to get the title/window details so you can later "look" for it.

2) You basically just need the sequence to capture current output. Such as:
`Alt+Space;E;S;` # mark everything
`Alt+Space;E;Y;` # copy

2) Make the script run periodically. See `loop` and `sleep` keywords.
You can even toggle the script via a variable:

```
F12::
stopit = 0
While stopit = 0
{
    Loop, 70
    {

        Click
        if stopit = 1
        {
                exit
        }    
    }
    Sleep, 2000

}
return


F10::
    stopit = 1
return
```

Source - user: left1000, via: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/54-loop-until-key-is-pressed/

3) Just write out the content you grab into a text file. https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm

I believe this could be copy-pasted together from the Autohotkey docs and Google within ~5-15 minutes. I cannot provide you a complete example / script because I don't know what application is this, I cannot test the script, etc. So this is as much as I can help in this case.